# How to create a nested list with parent and children?

Tags: c#, list, linq, nested

I want to create a list of Items with parent and children. I have already prepared the data in a sqlite file:

[image]

So I want to read this data (I can read data like `var subjectnames = await db.SubjectNames.ToListAsync();`) from the database and create a nested list based on being a parent and a child.Each item may have one or more children and the number is unknown.

this is my class:

```
public class SubjectName
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long ParentId { get; set; }
}

public class ExplorerItem : Observable
{
    public enum ExplorerItemType { Folder, File, CheckMark };
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ExplorerItem Parent { get; set; }
    public ExplorerItemType Type { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<ExplorerItem> m_children;
    public ObservableCollection<ExplorerItem> Children
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_children == null)
            {
                m_children = new ObservableCollection<ExplorerItem>();
            }
            return m_children;
        }
        set
        {
            m_children = value;
        }
    }

    private bool m_isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return m_isExpanded; }
        set { Set(ref m_isExpanded, value); }
    }
}
```

and i have a ObservableCollection of ExplorerItem:

```
var list = new ObservableCollection<ExplorerItem>();
```

That all data must be added to it

Once the data is completed, the list should be displayed as follows in TreeView

[image]

The problem is that I dont Know how to create parent-child relationships and add them to the list. Because their number is not known and they include parent and child nested

Comment: If you're using Entity Framework and I understand what's happening here can you use the Parent Table and pull a list from that? If not you'll have to set up another data object for parents probably that contains a list of children.

Comment: @Byrd no i cant use another table because each child may be a parent

Comment: Oh, so subjectId needs to match up with the parentId? Would something like newParentList.addrange(yourList.Where(x => x.subjectId == toCheckObj.ParentId).ToList())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<ExplorerItem> Subjects = new List<ExplorerItem>();

private async void GetSubjects()
    {
        var rootItems = await db.SubjectNames.Where(x=>x.ParentId == 0).ToListAsync();
        var subjectNames = await db.SubjectNames.ToListAsync();
        var subjects = await db.Subjects.ToListAsync();

        foreach (var root in rootItems)
        {
            var explorerItem = new ExplorerItem
            {
                Id = root.Id,
                SubjectId = root.SubjectId,
                Name = root.Name,
                Type = ExplorerItemType.Folder
            };
            
            var subjectNameChilds = subjectNames.Where(x => x.ParentId == root.SubjectId);

            if (subjectNameChilds.Any())
            {
                var childs = GetChilds(root, subjectNames, subjects, explorerItem);
                explorerItem.Children = new ObservableCollection<ExplorerItem>(childs);
            }
            Subjects.Add(explorerItem);
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<ExplorerItem> GetChilds(SubjectName subjectName, List<SubjectName> subjectNameList, List<Subjects> subjectList, ExplorerItem parent)
    {
        var subjectNameChilds = subjectNameList.Where(x => x.ParentId == subjectName.SubjectId);

        foreach (var root in subjectNameChilds)
        {
            var explorerItem = new ExplorerItem
            {
                Id = root.Id,
                SubjectId = root.SubjectId,
                Name = root.Name,
                Parent = parent
            };
            if (root.Type == 0)
            {
                explorerItem.Type = ExplorerItemType.Folder;
            }
            else
            {
                var child = subjectList.Where(x => x.SubjectId == root.SubjectId).Any();
                if (child)
                {
                    explorerItem.Type = ExplorerItemType.CheckMark;
                }
                else
                {
                    explorerItem.Type = ExplorerItemType.File;
                }
            }

            var childs = subjectNameList.Where(x => x.ParentId == root.SubjectId);

            if (childs.Any())
            {
                var chils = GetChilds(root, subjectNameList, subjectList, explorerItem);
                explorerItem.Children = new ObservableCollection<ExplorerItem>(chils);
                yield return explorerItem;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return explorerItem;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If using EF You can change the class and set the configuration as follows:

```
public class SubjectName
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public long SubjectId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public long ParentId { get; set; }
   public SubjectName Parent { get; set; }
   public ICollection<SubjectName> Chidren{ get; set; }
}

public class SubjectNameConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SubjectName>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SubjectName> builder)
    {
       builder.HasKey(e => e.SubjectId);

       // Relations
        builder.HasOne(d => d.Parent)
            .WithMany(p => p.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(d => d.SubjectId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```